# Junit replace properties

Tags: java, junit

I'd like to change from which `.properties` file class should get them.
My class is like this now:

```
public class MyClass {

private String str;    

public MyClass() throws IOException {
    loadProperties();
}

private void loadProperties() throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my.properties"));

    str= props.getProperty("property");        
}
```

And whyle testing i would like properties to be loaded from another file.
It's apache camel app, so i have this now:

```
public class ConverterTest {
    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new MyClass(); //--> Here i must load from another file             
    }

    @Test
    // test    
}
```

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass property file name to MyClass constructor

```
public MyClass(String propsFile) throws IOException {
    loadProperties(propsFile);
}
```

Comment: How efficient will it be? I will use this constructor only for tests. But I would like to know if it's possible to do as it is without adding stuff to my main class.

Answer (score 0):

There is something you can do:

```
public class MyClass {

private String str;    
private String path = "my.properties";

public MyClass() throws IOException {
    loadProperties();
}

protected void loadProperties() throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path));

    str= props.getProperty("property");        
}
```

And then, add a test to the same package with the code:

```
myClass = new MyClass();
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(path, "otherpathto.properties");
myClass.loadProperties();
```

It involves a small change in the code, but it might not be a big deal... depending on your project.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably the cleanest solution would be to refactor `MyClass` and remove dependency on `Properties` object and inject the values needed via the constructor instead. Your case proves that hidden and hardcoded dependencies complicate testing.

Responsibility for reading the properties file and injecting the value into `MyClass` could be pushed back to its caller:

```
public class MyClass {
    private final String str;    

    public MyClass(String strValue) {
        this.str = strValue;
    }

    // ...
}

public class ProductionCode {
    public someMethod() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my.properties"));
        String str = props.getProperty("property");

        MyClass obj = new MyClass(str);
        obj.foo();
    }
}

public class ConverterTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        String testStr = "str for testing";
        MyClass testee = new MyClass(testStr);
        testee.foo();
        // assertions
    }
}
```